# Find two different words in a file

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am starting with Python.

Here is the text I want to search on:

```
vlan 1111
   name "VLAN1111"
   untagged 2
   tagged 10
   no ip address
   exit
vlan 2222
   name "VLAN2222"
   untagged 5
   exit
vlan 3333
   name "VLAN3333"
   untagged 3
   no ip address
   exit
```

I'd like to search all the text "vlan xxxx". I want to return "vlan xxxx" if the I find the word "untagged" which is two lines below.

My code would be like this :

```
def find_vlan_untagged(file):
    vlan = re.findall(r'vlan \d{4}\n\n untagged', file)  # Finds VLAN

    if len(untagged) < 1:
        return 'No untagged VLAN'

    else:
        for each in vlan:
            return vlan xxxx
```

Please advise me on this, I think I am close :)

Comment: Your regex needs to deal properly with the "name" line, and with the blank spaces at the start of the "untagged" line. Are those asterisks in your data file? If so, the regex needs to deal with them too.

Comment: Thanks - The asterisks were supposed to put the word in Bold... In my mind, I would check two lines after the "vlan xxx" or extract a block of lines from "vlan xxxx" to "untagged". Does it make sense ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that does what you want. I added an extra entry to the data so we can see that the regex correctly handles an entry that doesn't fit the pattern you're looking for.

The key is to specify the multiline mode flag (with `re.M`), and to use non-greedy matching (with `*?`).

```
import re

data = '''\
vlan 1111
   name "VLAN1111"
   untagged 2
   tagged 10
   no ip address
   exit
vlan 2222
   name "VLAN2222"
   untagged 5
   exit
vlan 4444
   name "VLAN4444"
   tagged 44
   exit
vlan 3333
   name "VLAN3333"
   untagged 3
   no ip address
   exit
'''

pat = re.compile(r'^(vlan \d{4})\n.*?\n\s*untagged', re.M)
print(pat.findall(data))
```

**output**

```
['vlan 1111', 'vlan 2222', 'vlan 3333']
```

---

BTW,

```
for each in vlan:
    return vlan xxxx
```

doesn't do what you want: it will return from the function on the first iteration. I suggest that you simply return the whole list that `.findall` finds. Or you could make the function into a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) that yields each found item, one by one.

Comment: Sorry to coming back to you with some delay... Your code is working as expected :) Thank you very much for your help !